# How can I format data label and adding the title next to the value with swimlane/ngx-charts version 18.0.1?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I have this code

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
    [maxXAxisTickLength]=50
    [yAxisTickFormatting]="yAxisTickFormattingFn"
    [xAxisTickFormatting]="xAxisTickFormattingFn"
       [dataLabelFormatting]="dataLabelFormattingFn"
    [showDataLabel]="true"
    [results]="performance"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [legend]="false"
    [showXAxisLabel]="true"
    [showYAxisLabel]="true"
    [xAxis]="true"
    [yAxis]="true"
    [gradient]="false"
    >
    <ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model" >
      {{ tooltip(model) }}
      </ng-template>
 </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

and dataLabelFormattingFn is

```
dataLabelFormattingFn = this.dataLabelFormatting.bind(this);
```

where dataLabelFormatting

```
private dataLabelFormatting(value: number) {
      return value + "%";
  }
```

how to add the title next to the label is there is somthing like this maybe?

```
private dataLabelFormatting(value: number,title: number) {
      return title + value + "%";
  }
```

I have tried searching for the solution but cant find it